# SimpleAuth + Instagram + Swift, Code 400, OAuthException

Tags: ios, swift, authentication, instagram, instagram-api

I am using SimpleAuth to attempt to enable instagram authorization in my app.

As per SimpleAuth (https://github.com/calebd/SimpleAuth/wiki/Instagram) requirements, I've set it up like so:

```
SimpleAuth.configuration()["instagram"] = ["myclientid": "myclientid", SimpleAuthRedirectURIKey: "http://google.com"]
```

To initialize my instagram settings and this to set up my parameters:

```
SimpleAuth.authorize("instagram", options: ["scope" : ["likes", "comments"]], completion: { (responseObject : AnyObject!, error : NSError!) -> Void in })
```

In response I have been receiving this error:

```
{
    "code": 400,
    "error_type": "OAuthException",
    "error_message": "You must include a valid client_id, response_type, and redirect_uri parameters"
}
```

Also, when I use:

```
var response = responseObject as NSDictionary
```

I get a "Use of a unresolved identifier "response"Object" error.

I feel like I've tried almost everything, does anybody have any ideas?
Thanks ahead of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a wrong key in your configuration dictionary. You should use *client_id* instead of *myclientid*.

```
SimpleAuth.configuration()["instagram"] = ["client_id": "myclientid", SimpleAuthRedirectURIKey: "http://google.com"]
```